# Logic behind Malloc Function

Tags: memory-management, malloc

First of all sorry for my sloppy diagram below.

I want to understand logic behind malloc(). This was asked to me in Bloomberg interview.

**Que:Consider only 2 bytes of memory left in your OS (as shown below).Now if I malloc() it for 2 bytes.** (White region indicates free space in byte,and black indicates used space in byte. So we have 2-bytes free and 2-bytes used memory space).
[image: Memory Region]

- What does malloc() do?
- What does OS do in such scenario?
- Is malloc() will be successful, will it return 2 bytes? Say yes or no
  with explanation.

P.S:- I checked on google and I found it is dependent on OS mostly. But I would like to have more insight on it.

Thank you!

Comment: An OS typically allocates memory regions to processes in units of pages, so it's unlikely to only have 2 bytes left...

Comment: I answered the same but I guess he is not totally agreed with me on this.

Comment: Then it's difficult to know what to suggest here!  Either your interviewer was strange, or you've misremembered the question...

Comment: I remembered the question correctly. But I guess he is looking for more on logical explanation. That's why I posted it here to get insight on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of issues here (note that most of what's below is specific to Linux, but I guess will be similar on other platforms):

- A typical implementation of `malloc` will never allocate only 2 bytes (due to efficiency and alignment concerns).  For example, the standard GNU implementation allocates a minimum of 16 bytes by default, I think.
- `malloc` operates in user-space, on memory regions already provided by the OS.  The OS only gets involved once `malloc` exhausts what it has available and needs to request a bigger memory region for the heap.
- The OS must allocate memory regions to processes in units of pages (typically 4kB), as this is the fundamental unit of the hardware memory-management unit (MMU).  Therefore, it doesn't make sense to talk about the OS only having 2 bytes left.
- The OS usually allocates memory regions that don't currently map to any physical memory (this is known as *overcommitting*).  A physical mapping is only created when the process tries to access the memory.
- If the OS gets low on physical memory, it uses a system known as *page-frame reclaiming* to steal page frames from other processes.

So in short, the scenario described in your question is unlikely to occur, for several reasons!